# Angular templating and routing with jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-routing, angular-template

I'm working on my first angular website with templating and routing.

I want a image that is the size of window - 70px

//Jquery (This part works fine alone, tested it.)

```
    //Dynamically assign height
function reSize() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height() - 70;

    $('.home .image img').height(windowHeight);
}

//Initial load of page
$( window ).ready(reSize);

//Every resize of window
$(window).resize(reSize);
```

My problem is that when I load my home.html(where the picture is and also act as the frontpage) into index.html it doesn't apply the style `windowHeight` to the image, but if I manually just resize the window a bit, then the style applies.

I tried inserting my script directly into home.html and then it works but I would prefer to have the jquery separate in a .js file

My guess is that my script doesn't registrer that home.html has been loaded into index.html until the resize has been triggered.

Note: all stylesheets and scripts are loaded in index.html head, and pages that are loaded into index.html by ng-view looks like this at the moment

```
<div class="image"><img src="images/56.jpg"></div>
```

Sorry for the bad explanation, I'm new with angular so I don't completely understand it yet.

Thank you.

Comment: You should try wrapping the jQuery in angular's $timeout service with a timeout of 0 so that'll it'll run when angular is ready. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing jquery markup with angular markup.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are 2 options, where you can trigger this:

on state change success

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
    // run resize function
});
```

or on view rendered callback

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    // run resize function
});
```

hope that helps.